# Is it OK to use multi line regular expression to comment out code in Ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby, comments

When commenting out codes in ruby we have 2 main options

1. Adding sharp to start of the line `# puts "somecode"`
2. Putting your code between 
   `=start 
   puts "somecode" 
   =end`

I am lazy and sometimes i put the code between slashes like the code below. Its crates a multiple line regex expression. What kind of side effects this practice can cause?

CODE

```
puts "hello"
/
puts "world"
/
puts "peace"
```

OUTPUT

```
hello
peace
```

Comment: Yeah, just don't do `/puts "#{stop_the_cooling_system_on_the_nuclear_plant}"/`.

Comment: I.e. this type of commenting is not safe for anything critical, because it is still possible to execute code inside a Ruby regexp.

Comment: Better get to know your editor. About all of them allow block commenting where you just highlight the lines to be commented / uncommented and press a shortcut, e.g. `CMD` + `/` in Atom.

Comment: I agree with everyone: let editor help. However, if you're dead-set on non-comment block comment, use `if false ... end`, which can't have any side-effects (and include a comment so no-one trying to read the code thinks you're crazy, just weird.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Tadman's example

```
def example
  do_important_stuff!
  /
  other(thing: true)
  do_super_important_stuff(factor: 9000)
  /
  do_other_stuff
end
```

This creates a Regex object every time the method is called, which is not free. It takes time, memory and extra work for the garbage collection process.

Answer (score 1):

As Holger points out, most editors have "toggle comments" which makes for a much more reliable way to enable/disable chunks of code. This is the recommended method. Your regular expression approach is too lazy by half, it would be utterly baffling to anyone reading the code at a glance to verify what's going on.

Making commits with inadvertently disabled code is a thing that will happen, so you want your comments to be both obvious and easy to repair.

Which one looks better:

```
def example
  do_important_stuff!
  /
  other(thing: true)
  do_super_important_stuff(factor: 9000)
  /
  do_other_stuff
end
```

Versus the more intuitive:

```
def example
  do_important_stuff!
  # other(thing: true)
  # do_super_important_stuff(factor: 9000)
  do_other_stuff
end
```

As with many editors, Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting immediately shows that there's code here that's commented out. The other version just looks *bizarre*.

If you find it too tedious to enable/disable commenting you probably need to let your editor help you out, or configure it to make it easier to do that.